# How do I check if user input is found in array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to check if user input is equal to the data I have in my arrays, 
then printing the int array that corresponds with the string array,
but nothing appears when I run the program.

What am I doing wrong?

This is everything I have in my main method:

```
  String firstname;
  String middleinitial;

  System.out.println("What is your first name?");
  firstname = myScan.nextLine();

  System.out.println("What is your middle initial?");
  middleinitial = myScan.nextLine();

 String[] firstNameLetter = {"A", "Albert", "Alice", "Ann", "Anna", "Annie",        "Arthur", 
            "B", "Bernard", "Bette", "Bettie", "Betty", "C", "Carl",
            "Catherine", "Charles", "Clara", "D", "Donald", "Dorothy, E",
            "Edward", "Elizabeth", "F", "Florence", "Frank", "G", "George",
            "Grace", "H", "Harold", "Harriet", "Harry", "Hazel", "Helen",      "Henry",
            "I", "J", "James", "Jane", "Jayne", "Jean", "John", 
            "Joan", "Joseph", "K", "L", "M", "Margaret", "Martin",
            "Marvin", "Mary", "Melvin", "Mildred", "N", "O", "P",
            "Patricia", "Paul", "Q", "R", "Richard", "Ruby", "Robert",
            "Ruth", "S", "T", "Thelma", "Thomas", "U", "V",
            "W", "Walter", "Wanda", "William", "Wilma", "X", "Y",
            "Z"};

    int[] firstNameNumber     = {000, 020, 020, 040, 040, 040, 040,
             060, 80, 80, 80, 80, 100, 120,
             120, 140, 140, 160, 180, 180, 200,
             220, 220, 240, 260, 260, 280, 300,
             300, 320, 340, 340, 360, 360, 380, 380,
             400, 420, 440, 440, 440, 460, 460,
             480, 480, 500, 520, 540, 560, 560,
             580, 580, 600, 600, 620, 640, 660,
             680, 680, 700, 720, 740, 740, 760,
             760, 780, 800, 820, 820, 840, 860,
             880, 900, 900, 920, 920, 940, 960,
             980};

String[] middleNameLetter = {" ", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
             "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M",
             "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
             "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

int[] middleNameNumber    = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
                             7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
                             14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 17, 18,
                             18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19};

for (int count = 0; count < firstNameLetter.length; count++)
{
    if (firstname.equals(firstNameLetter[count]))
    {
        System.out.println(firstNameNumber[count]);
    }
}

for (int count = 0; count < middleNameLetter.length; count++)
{
    if (middleinitial.equals(middleNameLetter[count]))
    {
        System.out.println(middleNameNumber[count]);
    }
}
```

Comment: for my opinion,if you can use hashMap,it will be more better than array.for example Map map = new HashMap();map.put(000,"abc"),map.put(002,"def").then if you want to check user input is contain ,then you can do like that:for (ArrayList<String> value: map.values()) {
    // using ArrayList#contains
    System.out.println(value.contains("myString"));
}.then you can also print the key easily.

Comment: Does your first two sysouts print correct values?

Answer (score 1):

When I ran this code myself all seemed to be working. I see nothing wrong with your logic. You must have a typo in there somewhere.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String firstname;
    String middleinitial;

    System.out.println("What is your first name?");
    firstname = myScan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What is your middle initial?");
    middleinitial = myScan.nextLine();

    String[] firstNameLetter = {"A", "Albert", "Alice", "Ann", "Anna", 
        "Annie","Arthur", "B", "Bernard", "Bette", "Bettie", "Betty", 
        "C", "Carl", "Catherine", "Charles", "Clara", "D", "Donald", 
        "Dorothy, E", "Edward", "Elizabeth", "F", "Florence", "Frank", 
        "G", "George", "Grace", "H", "Harold", "Harriet", "Harry", "Hazel",
        "Helen", "Henry", "I", "J", "James", "Jane", "Jayne", "Jean", 
        "John", "Joan", "Joseph", "K", "L", "M", "Margaret", "Martin",
        "Marvin", "Mary", "Melvin", "Mildred", "N", "O", "P",
        "Patricia", "Paul", "Q", "R", "Richard", "Ruby", "Robert",
        "Ruth", "S", "T", "Thelma", "Thomas", "U", "V",
        "W", "Walter", "Wanda", "William", "Wilma", "X", "Y",
        "Z"};

    int[] firstNameNumber = {000, 020, 020, 040, 040, 040, 040,
                             060, 80, 80, 80, 80, 100, 120,120,
                             140, 140, 160, 180, 180, 200, 220, 
                             220, 240, 260, 260, 280, 300, 300,
                             320, 340, 340, 360, 360, 380, 380,
                             400, 420, 440, 440, 440, 460, 460,
                             480, 480, 500, 520, 540, 560, 560,
                             580, 580, 600, 600, 620, 640, 660,
                             680, 680, 700, 720, 740, 740, 760,
                             760, 780, 800, 820, 820, 840, 860,
                             880, 900, 900, 920, 920, 940, 960, 980};  

    String[] middleNameLetter = {" ", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
                                 "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M",
                                 "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
                                 "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

    int[] middleNameNumber = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
                              7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
                              14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 17, 18,
                              18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19};

    for (int count = 0; count < firstNameLetter.length; count++) {
        if (firstname.equals(firstNameLetter[count])) {
            System.out.println(firstNameNumber[count]);
        }
    }

    for (int count = 0; count < middleNameLetter.length; count++) {
        if (middleinitial.equals(middleNameLetter[count])) {
            System.out.println(middleNameNumber[count]);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: there's a "typo" in the logic if he wants those first 8 integers as their integer values and not their octal values :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of `equals()` and may also want to add a `break` statement in the for loops to stop iterating if the strings match.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the array into a list and use the method. [list.contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object))
    Arrays.asList(firstNameLetter).contains(firstname);

etc etc for all the given inputs

Comment: That won't give him the int in the second array.

Answer (score 0):

As a sanity check, are you able to recompile this successfully?  In trying to run your solution I found the `Scanner` instance was not being declared.  Adding the following:

`Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);`

allowed me to run with following output:

```
$java ScannerTest
What is your first name?
Henry
What is your middle initial?
A
380
1
```

Comment: yeah whoops I had scanner declared in my original code i forgot to paste it in here i'm sorry about that

Comment: Does that solve the issue? Or are you still having issues getting it to recognize your input?

Answer (score 0):

Your program is working correctly (other than the missing `Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);` that you likely have and didn't repeat).

What may be confusing you is that you've defined several of your integers as octal values.  When you begin an integer with a `0` value it is declared as an octal.

For example, the second value, corresponding to Albert, is `020`.  This is an octal value for 16.

As others have mentioned, you likely want to use `equalsIgnoreCase()` on your strings and `break;` from inside the loops.  Also having two equal length arrays is dangerous; much better to store the values in pairs in a `HashMap` or other structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(str.toLowerCase().equals())
```